# Split screen with custom ratio

Tags: windows-7, display

I have Windows 7 and a 23" full HD screen. I really enjoy the split screen (snap) functionality, but 50/50 isn't always what I need. Sometimes 70/30 or whatever is more appropriate.

How can I split the screen into arbitrarily-sized sections for purposes of window arrangement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/

[image]

Comment: Great it works for you! =)

Comment: any open source equivalent of this app?? need to use this in my office :(